# using php code inside an echo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My question to you is how do I get the code below to `echo` its entirety? I have multiples of these that I need to `echo` using `while` and I have toyed with it but have yet to figure out what to do. The answers I have seen, I have tried but they just don't work on my code. I need to have all this code here in one bunch but I am having an issue inserting the "like button" section. The issue starts at

```
$likes = (empty($_POST['like'])) ? : $_POST['like'] ;
```

and here's the full code

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo ' 
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
<div class="logo-logo"><h2>Questions.</h2>
<div class="checkboxes">'.$row['formtype'].'
</div>

</div>
<div class="top-submit">
&#8220'. $row["actual_quote"] . '&#8221;
</div>
<div class="poster">- '. $row["poster"].'
 <div class = "like">- '.
  $likes = (empty($_POST['like'])) ? : $_POST['like'] ;
  $dislikes = (empty($_POST['dislike'])) ? : $_POST['dislike'] ;
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  if(isset($_POST['like'])){
    $likes1 = $likes+1;
    $voted1 = $voted+1;
    $query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO voters (voted, ip) VALUES ( :voted, :ip)");
    $query2->bindParam(':voted', $voted1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query2->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $query2->execute();
    header("Location: like.php?");
    $update1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO votes (likes) VALUES ( :likes)");
    $update1->bindParam(':likes', $likes1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update1->execute();
  }

  if(isset($_POST['dislike'])){
    $dislikes1 = $dislikes+1;
    $voted1 = $voted+1;
    $query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO voters (voted, ip) VALUES ( :voted, :ip)");
    $query2->bindParam(':voted', $voted1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query2->bindParam(':ip', $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $query2->execute();
    header("Location: like.php?");
    $update1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO votes (dislikes) VALUES ( :dislikes)");
    $update1->bindParam(':dislikes', $dislikes1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update1->execute();
  }
  $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM voters");
  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $row3 = $stmt->fetch();

  echo "Likes: $likes <br /> Dislikes: $dislikes<br />";

  if(isset($row3['voted'])){
    if(isset($row3['ip'])){
      echo "You have already voted for this.";
    }
  } else {

    echo "<form action = '' method = 'post'> <input type = 'submit' name = 'like' value  = 'like'> <input type = 'submit' name = 'dislike' value = 'dislike'></form>";

  }'
</div>
<!-- use select to get the items to stay on the page-->

</div>
</div>
</div>
';
}
```

There may be a very simple solution but I have searched everywhere for it. I have tried using a `.` at the end but it doesn't like that. Any suggestions?

**EDIT** I have changed one portion, the whole code starting at `$likes` and ending after `else{}` has been put as this:

```
  <div class = "like">';
  include("like.php");
  echo'</div>
```

Comment: After `<div class="like">`, you don't end your statement.  You just keep concatenating.  Don't do that.  You can use multiple `echo` statements and they will be output in a row, as if it were just one.  Really though you will find that this sort of code will be hard to maintain in the future.  Consider a template engine.  Also consider that right now you are likely wide open to XSS attacks and other injection issues since you aren't escaping any output for use in HTML.

Comment: Firstly, ternary operators go something like this `$Start = isset($_REQUEST["start"]) ? $_REQUEST["start"] : 0;` you've got `? :` with nothing in between. Another thing, as soon as your headers kick in, your next query below them, die and fly off into cyberspace.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You stop your echo, do your other code, and start echoing again.

```
echo 'foo';
bar();
echo 'baz';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am kind of confused on where to put bar();  and how to use it, I tried to research it but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Ahh, okay sorry that was a stupid question, haha, but now the while is not continuing, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use echo in this way.

Try to keep your HTML in variable and concatenate all needed additional HTML using dot after checking all necessary conditions.

```
$output = '<div>blahblah</div>';
if ($somedatafromDB == true) {
  $output .= '<p>true!!</p>';
} else {
  $output .= '<p>false :/</p>';
}

// and finally
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

An issue might also be the ternary operator:

Your code is currently

```
$likes = (empty($_POST['like'])) ? : $_POST['like'] ;
```

Try to change it to

```
$likes = (empty($_POST['like'])) ? 0 : $_POST['like'];
```

You need to specify what you would like to return if the `$_POST['like']` is empty.

The ternary operator (`x?y:z`) returns `y` if `x` is true, else it returns `z`. In your case `y` is missing which might cause an error during execution.

A good practice is `ini_set("display_errors", "on");` at the beginning of the script for debugging purposes.